# Why does NSToolbarItem get disabled automatically?

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nsbutton, nstoolbar

I have a bit of an issue with buttons in the toolbar of my slideshow application for Mac.

I want those buttons to be disabled when there is no active slideshow and enabled when there is an active slideshow. In order to achieve this, I set the buttons' `isEnabled` property to `false` at the start (I have tried both Interface Builder and my window's `windowDidLoad`) and then in the `didSet` of my slideshow variable I do the following:

```
var slideshow: Slideshow? {
    didSet {
        self.playPauseButton.isEnabled = slideshow != nil
    }
}
```

What happens is that the buttons (only one in this example) are enabled for about half a second and then disabled again.

I've set a breakpoint on the `didSet` to confirm that slideshow isn't set to `nil` at some point. I'm also not modifying `isEnabled` anywhere else in my code. For testing I've set `isEnabled = true` instead of `false` just to see what happens and it turns out the buttons stay enabled then.

Might there be some part of AppKit that automatically disables the buttons for some reason I don't know about? I hope someone might have an idea.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017822/how-to-enable-disable-nstoolbaritem ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I managed to fix the problem.

It did turn out to be an issue with the validation of NSToolbarItems as in the question matt linked to. However, simply overriding the function `validateToolbarItem` in my NSWindowController subclass did not do the job as the function is not called for NSToolbarItems with views in them ([see Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Toolbars/Tasks/ValidatingTBItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000753)).

To get around that, I had to subclass NSToolbarItem and override its `validate` function to call `validateToolbarItem` on its target as described in the answer to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42470645/nstoolbaritem-validation-in-relevant-controller).